# Activity run only once at first time

Tags: android, parcelable

I've a class that implements Parcelable interface. 
I want an Activity that run only once at the first run of app, in this Activity I create the user (name, surname, ... ). After the first run, and after the user is created, another layout is displayed.
Can anyone help me with an example?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Someone recommended this library to me once upon a time and I thought it was a good library to use in scenarios like yours.

https://github.com/jonfinerty/Once

Try the once library for what you want to do.

Alternatively, you can also saved down a variable in your sharedPreference to show that the activity you want to run has already run, so that next time you switch on the app, it doesn't run again.